# Search results are not displayed in lists

Tags: list, search-results, crawl

Search in any list returns an empty result.
After full crawl in Search Service Application Logs:

```
http://portal.cmx.ru/Lists/ReferencesToPlaceOfEmployees/AllItems.aspx 
This URL uses V3 format and will be deleted. This will be recrawled using V4 format ( SearchID = 18799C2D-E06B-4F9D-95A6-63BBDD40FA10 )

http://portal.cmx.ru/Lists/ReferencesToPlaceOfEmployees/AllItems.aspx 
Deleted by the gatherer ( This item was deleted because its parent was deleted. )

http://portal.cmx.ru/Lists/ReferencesToPlaceOfEmployees/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
Deleted by the gatherer ( This item was deleted because its parent was deleted. )
...
```

As far as I understand, the results of search in the lists are not displayed, therefore all lists are deleted in the same way.

Can someone tell me how to fix the search in the lists or what is this v4 format?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reset Index and Full Crawl fixed the problem